# Can i make an XSLT transformation directly in html page?

Tags: html, xml, xhtml, xslt, doctype

I know namespace are used to describe, like doctype, but is there a way or a trick to transform inner namespace html with an xsl using xsd ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xmlns:sample="sample-uri">
    <head >
        <title>Enter the title of your XHTML document here</title>
    </head>
    <body >
        <p sample:node="retrieve-transformation">Enter the body text of your XHTML document here</p>

</html>
```

In other words i want to know if i can process xsl transformation to an xhtml page whithout using javascript.

Comment: It is not clear from your posting what your question is and what you are trying to do. Could you be more specific? Like giving an example of your input and expected output document?

Comment: If I am reading this properly, @belaz wishes to perform an XSL transformation in the middle of an HTML document.

Comment: So why didn't you write this in the first place ;)

Comment: I wanted to hear about a specific namespace prefix trick ;D, but i will take whatever information you give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern browsers support XSLT out of the box.

Take a look at [eu.wowarmory.com](http://eu.wowarmy.com) - they use it extensively. If the server detects a user agent that does not support XSLT, it is rendered at the server side, and a quite verbose HTML is rendered there and sent to the browser.

This makes a nice abstraction if you plan to provide an XML webservice similar to the web site.

Answer (score 4):

In XHTML (i.e. `application/xhtml+xml`—not `text/html`!), you can trigger an XSLT program without JavaScript using the [`xml-stylesheet` processing instruction](http://simon.html5.org/specs/xml-stylesheet5).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot perform an XSL transformation without using some kind of scripting technology. I would suggest you do it serverside to save the client the trouble; and to avoid various issues if the transformation for some reason does not succeed on the client or runs slow.